# Transferring static class variables in java

Tags: java, variables, methods, static-classes

My problem is that when i try to use the monster method then the method doesnt really work as i want it to work the thing that seems to be the most wrong is the items variable. There is also an issue with rolling the dice in the monster method because when you role a 1 which should kill you then nothing happens. The entire code is quite large so ill only include the parts that is involved. A link to the entire code can be found here: http://justpaste.it/marcs
Here's what happens when monster method is triggered with 2 items:

```
//Du behöver hitta 2 objekt för att slåss mot bossen
```

This line shouldnt come up.

```
//Du möter en stor fet boss! Det är Slavechan!

//Om du slår en 1:a så trampar han på dig.
//Du slog 1
```

here i should have died

```
//Du gör dig redo att slåss mot Slavechan.

//Slavechan dör från en överdos av ris.
//Du tar allt ris han hade och springer iväg mot solnedgången.
//Du Springer in i en osynlig synlig dörr och dör. 


public class Spel
{
static Rum rum5;
static Rum current;
static Rum rum12 = new Rum("Du hittar ingenting. " , "En väg. ");
static boolean items = false;
public static void main(String[] args) {
Rum rum13 = new Rum("Du Springer in i en osynlig synlig dörr och dör. ", "Ett slott. ");

rum13.boss = new monster();

    }
```

rum2

```
if (current.item1 != null){
        current.visited = true;
        }
```

rum5

```
  if (current.item2 != null){
        current.visited = true;
        }
```

rum9

```
   if (current.item3 != null){
        current.visited = true;
        }
    boolean items = ((rum9.visited==true) || (rum2.visited==true) && (rum5.visited==true));
```

The entire monster code

```
public class monster {

public void rulla1(){
if (Spel.items == false){
System.out.println("Du behöver hitta 2 objekt för att slåss mot bossen");
Spel.current = Spel.rum12;
}else
                try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
System.out.println("Du möter en stor fet boss! Det är Slavechan!");
System.out.println(" ");
                try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
 System.out.println("Om du slår en 1:a så trampar han på dig.");
 int rull1 = (int)(Math.random() * ((12 - 1) + 1));
 System.out.println("Du slog " +rull1);
 if (rull1 == 1){
 Spel.current=null;
 }else
                    try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
 System.out.println("Du gör dig redo att slåss mot Slavechan.");
 System.out.println(" ");
            try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
System.out.println("Slavechan dör från en överdos av ris.");
            try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
 System.out.println("Du tar allt ris han hade och springer iväg mot solnedgången.");
                try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
 Spel.current = null;
 }
 }
```

Sorry for Swedish comments

Comment: I'm not sure but you seem to declare a local variable boolean items, you don't use the static variable you declared in your Spel class...

Comment: @thijsraets Do you mean that im trying to use it in the wrong way?

Comment: well by writing: "boolean items = ... ", you don't set the static variable but just a new variable that's only visible locally, since you don't really have code after this declaration this variable isn't used. But I guess I'm missing something ;)  (FIX: just write "items = ..." )

Comment: Add something like this? `if (current.item1 != null || current.item2 != null || current.item3 != null) items = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going into the quality of your code, but this is a quick fix that actually 
gives the player the opportunity to play the game until its end.

1) intialize the static *rum5*  in the Spel class because you refer to it in trap:

```
static Rum rum5 = new Rum("Du hittade en flaska med en vätska i. ", "En grotta. ");
```

2) remove the local variable in the main method:

```
Rum rum5 = new Rum("Du hittade en flaska med en vätska i. ", "En grotta. ");
```

3) remove the boolean part from your items
`boolean items = ...` should be `items = ...`

3) How I played it:

try to go to room 9 (since this will set items = true once you hit room 6),
 now go to room 8 and afterwards room 7,
 hope you fall into the trap, this looks like the only way to get to room 5,
 from room 5 go to room 6 (this way items = true will be set because you visited room 9),
 play the room 6 right and you will go to room 5,
 get to room 13

4) Remarks:

I don't see how one can set rum2.visited = true since it has no items, that's why
 I visited room 9 to get items = true and not room 2 and 5